# convert integer date into formatted text

Tags: php

I have an sql database with a date column like this yyyymmdd (20111109), i usually sort my return queries by the date.

I would like to know how to convert this to the (D jS M) or (Wed 9th Nov).

For the month, date, and ordinal suffix, im using substr along with case. but its the weekday im getting frustrated with.

Is there a simpler method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in something more sophisticated:

```
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20111109');
  echo $date->format('D jS M');
```

This should be more reliable in the long run.

Comment: Wow. this is exactly what i was looking for. exactly!

Comment: Don't forget that this only works in PHP >= 5.3. 5.2.x will give you an error when trying to use DateTime::createFromFormat(). A workaround for it is to use Zend Framework's Zend_Date.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = strtotime($your_string);
$formatted_date = date('D jS M', $date);
echo $formatted_date;
```

Comment: Ah. thanks a million man. I didnt think strtotime would work like that

Comment: Np ;) Don't forget to set your default timezone, if you haven't already. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

with a combination of those you can achieve:

```
echo date("D j, M", strtotime(20111109));
```